# How do you send a base64 image to Discord WebHook?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, base64, discord.js, webhooks

I have tried the following code:

```
const Hook = new Discord.WebhookClient(DiscordWebHookID, DiscordWebHookToken);

const image = 'data:image/PNG;base64,R0lGODlhPQBEAPeoAJosM...'; //sample bit64image

const imageStream = new Buffer.from(image.split("base64,")[1],'base64');
const attachment =  new Discord.MessageAttachment(imageStream);

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().attachFile(attachment);

Hook.send(embed);
```

I have confirmed that the embedded message is sent when I remove the attachment property.

Comment: What is the problem with the following code?

Comment: No image is posted inside the channel @PLASMAchicken

Comment: In the latest version it is attachFiles not attachFile, so consider updating.

Answer (score 0):

If you change ".attachFile" to ".attachFiles", your code will work perfectly fine.
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=attachFiles

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I'm still left with no message in the channel.

Comment: Your bit64 image might be wrong, I tested the cod eon my machine and it was working, just with that slight change.

Comment: You can view my code here: https://gist.github.com/LiamTownsley/fb20d404a3451b667fbfddd9298fafc1